# List of Active Directory groups not showing from PowerShell code

Tags: powershell, csv, ansible, active-directory, group

I input a list of groups for each user in CSV, and tried to create users using PowerShell code.

This is the PowerShell code:

```
  - name: Change group for AD users
    ansible.windows.win_powershell: 
      script: |     
        [CmdletBinding()]
        param (
            [array]
            $datalist
        )

        $output = foreach ($user in $datalist) {
          $name = $user.SamAccountName
          $groups = $user.Groups
          $users = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$name'" 
          Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$name'" -Properties MemberOf | ForEach-Object {$_.MemberOf | Remove-ADGroupMember -Members $users -Confirm:$false}
          Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $groups -Members $users
        }

      parameters:
        datalist: "{{ hostvars.localhost.list }}"
```

I ended up getting this error:

```
"message": "Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADGroup' required by parameter 'Identity'. Specified method is not supported."
```

Also tried `'$groups'`:

```
"message": "Cannot find an object with identity: '$groups' under: 'DC=adexample,DC=local'.",
```

And `"$groups"`:

```
"message": "Cannot find an object with identity: 'CN=GroupA,OU=Groups,DC=adexample,DC=local CN=Test Group,OU=Groups,DC=adexample,DC=local' under: 'DC=adexample,DC=local'.",
```

This is how I input my list of groups into the CSV file:

| Groups |
| --- |
| CN=GroupA,OU=Groups,DC=adexample,DC=local;CN=Test Group,OU=Groups,DC=adexample,DC=local |
| CN=GroupA,OU=Groups,DC=adexample,DC=local;CN=Test Group,OU=Groups,DC=adexample,DC=local |

What is the right way to write $groups so that my list of groups can be output correctly?

**Updated with CSV in plain text:**

FirstName,SamAccountName,path,UserPrincipalName,Groups

Greg,gre.b87,"OU=Temporary Users,DC=adexample,DC=local",gre.b87@gmail.com,"CN=GroupA,OU=Groups,DC=adexample,DC=local;CN=Test Group,OU=Groups,DC=adexample,DC=local"

Zee,zeef.cd,"OU=Temporary Users,DC=adexample,DC=local",zeef.cd@gmail.com,"CN=GroupA,OU=Groups,DC=adexample,DC=local;CN=Test Group,OU=Groups,DC=adexample,DC=local"

I adapted bhuvanachand komara's to mine and it worked for me:

```
    $output = foreach ($user in $datalist) {
        $name = $user.SamAccountName
        $groups = $user.Groups -split ";"
        Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$samname'" 
        $users = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$samname'" 
          foreach ($group in $groups) {
            Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Members $user
          }
        Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$samname'" -Properties MemberOf | ForEach-Object {$_.MemberOf | Remove-ADGroupMember -Members $users -Confirm:$false}
     }
```

The main thing is that I need to add $groups = $user.Groups -split ";" and another foreach loop for the groups.

Comment: Please edit your question and copy paste as plain text how your CSV looks like as well as the code you're using to import it

Comment: Without seeing how literally your CSV looks like we would be just guessing on the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$csvFile = 'path\to\csv\file.csv'

$users = Import-Csv -Path $csvFile

foreach ($user in $users) {
    $samAccountName = $user.SamAccountName
    $givenName = $user.GivenName
    $surname = $user.Surname
    $password = $user.Password
    $email = $user.Email
    $groups = $user.Groups -split ","

    $securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $password -AsPlainText -Force
    New-ADUser -SamAccountName $samAccountName -GivenName $givenName -Surname $surname -DisplayName "$givenName $surname" -EmailAddress $email -AccountPassword $securePassword -Enabled $true

    foreach ($group in $groups) {
        Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Members $samAccountName
    }
}
```

Example CSV

SamAccountName,GivenName,Surname,Password,Email,Groups
user1,chand,komara,Password1,user1@example.com,group1,group2
user2,bhuvan,unnava,Password2,user2@example.com,group2,group3

For each user in the $users array, the code creates a new Active Directory user using the New-ADUser cmdlet with the specified SamAccountName,
GivenName, Surname, DisplayName, EmailAddress, and account password.
It then adds the user to the specified groups using the Add-ADGroupMember cmdlet.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just need to add  $groups = $user.Groups -split ";" and the foreach loop for groups to resolve the problem.